# A form that is able to be Modal after it is created

Tags: delphi

I have a `PopForm` that I want to stay over `MainForm` in any case.
The cases are:

`PopForm.ShowModal` and `PopForm.Show`.

Whilst `ShowModal` is completely works fine, the `Show` method is needed to interact with `MainForm` for doing 'drag-drop' things.

Main duty of the `PopForm` is to import data from some files to a dataset on the `MainForm`. There is two ways: drag-drop of the concrete data (selected rows while in Show-mode) and transfering all data from `PopForm` (while in ShowModal-mode). All data in the `PopForm` stored in something like `ClientDataSet`. I developed methods that are alike `ClientDataSet's`: First, Eof, FieldByName, Next, etc. and implemented them into `PopForm`.

After the `PopForm` is closed (after setting the ModalResult), the calling procedure uses a `while not PopForm.eof do PopForm.Next...` to import data into `MainForm's` dataset or whatever would be a user-programmers method.

For showing some progress I used to recreate `PopForm` with `Show` method and show a progress form above `PopForm`, while a cycle is being made in the calling procedure. After that - `PopForm` is closed.

This works fine, but the only problem is about a `Show` method - I need the `PopForm` to be over `MainForm` all the time. In most cases it is, but there are some applications, that somehow doesn't follow this rule. I've tried to use `PopupParent & PopupMode` properties, but they make `popForm` to recreate again on any assignment (and as I've just found - you need to assign a CustomForm on show and then - Nil it on close, because with common `TForm.Close` method it won't hide no way)

There would be no any problem about that, if there would be no need to Nil PopupParent on FormClose method. The other routine is to assign

```
...FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
  ...
end;
```

It would work if `Assigned(PopForm)` return `false`, but it returns `true`.

If there is any case to discover if the Form is Freed - that may help. What do you think?

Comment: This has been discussed many times by many people, and the answer is there's no true 100% way to guarantee it will always be on top of all other windows. What if another application also attempts the same? Who's to say which application should take priority? Fact is, even with the best method to stay on top, you still face the chance of it fighting with another application.

Comment: @Jerry - I don't think there's a stayontop form in the scenario. However I don't think I understand the issue or the question either.

Comment: @Sertac Indeed, it seemed to be multiple questions, that was the one that stood out to me... `I need the PopForm to be over MainForm all the time. In most cases it is, but there are some applications, that somehow doesn't follow this rule. `

Comment: @JerryDodge , @SertacAkyuz is right. There is no issue about other active apps. I did mean, that `PopForm` is used in several developed apps by other developers. I need to be 'optional' and 'universal' - that was the message and my conditions. So there is no multiple questions: it is all about how to make a form to be on Top of the calling form in both cases: ShowModal and Show.

Comment: I see nothing in your question mentioning this critical piece of information. Multiple applications working together is extremely important for us to know.

Comment: Pardon me, you have said, that *This has been discussed many times by many people, and the answer is there's no true 100% way to guarantee it will always be on top of all other windows. What if another application also attempts the same?* And I am telling you, that I don't care about other apps trying to get on top. I need that in a single app this form should be on top of the other form (of the same app). If there is other apps - I don't care what they do. The only issue - is relations between two forms `PopForm` and `MainForm` of same app. Did I clarify this point?

Comment: Then you need to re-word `but there are some applications, that somehow doesn't follow this rule.`

Comment: @notricky - How about some short code that duplicates the problem, instead of we trying to understand from the description of the issue.

Comment: I cannot re-word in the main topic, but a re-word here: *but there are some projects, that doesn't follow this rule*. That makes sense?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I have now idea on how I can show this issue in a code. In most projects the `PopForm` stays above `MainForm` (when I click on it) without any efforts (no fsStayOnTop, PopupParent all in Show mode etc), but also there are projects, where it doens't work and if  I click `MainForm` - the `PopForm` hides behind the main.

Comment: Check if you can if they all have the same mainformontaskbar setting.

Comment: Oh, you were so right about it!

Comment: And now the rest question left - how it is possible to force a pre-created Form in both ShowModal and Show modes to be on top, while user can click on the Main form?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your form style to fsStayOnTop the form will always stay on top unles you there is another form with same property. In that case the active one of them will be on top.

As for moving data from your PopForm which you use for importing data you could folow similar approach as it is used in creating of custom Dialogs.
Custom dialogs are usually designed like so:
You have dialog class which contains fields for dialg settings (to change hoe the dialog woul look like), and even a field for dialog output (selected FileMame/s, etc.).
Within this class there is a dialog form class which esentially is a modal form. This dialog form uses its OnClose event to automatically feed necessary information into Dialog output field before closing.

Comment: Did I understood you as if you suggest to create a Custom Class that will hold whole data (Datasets of the Dialog) and all the fetchig steps would be made to this class, while the Dialog class is a proprty in that Custom class?

Comment: Yes, I have added the fsStayOnTop and this seems to work. And it was so earlier. And first I got an error - Im starting to remember what is the problem - its hard to debug, because top window is OnTop of debugger ;))